# Android - Scraping HTML from one div class that repeats

Tags: android, html, web-scraping

Good afternoon everybody, first of all I hope this is the correct place to ask this.  I fear the question may be closed because it is in the wrong place but I think it fits here so here goes...

I want to scrape information from a webpage and display it in a widget on Android.  I want to scrape information from a class called "blogbody" but this class appears multiple times in the webpage.  The information I require is in the third instance of "blogbody", how can I scrape this information correctly?

Below is an example from the website (www.crossfit.com).

```
<td width="440" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">
<table width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top">      
    <div class="date">  August 17, 2012 </div>      
    <div class="blogbody">      
    <a name="8553"></a>
    <h3 class="title">Friday 120817</h3>
    <p>Snatch balance 1-1-1-1-1-1-1</p>
    <p>Post loads to comments.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a good HTML parser for this, I recommend [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/), It pretty quick & very flexible if your needs change in the future, it's also very simple to use.
You will be able to find many helpful questions in stack overflow itself.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have been experimenting with Jsoup but really am not sure how to differentiate between the different uses of "blogbody"  I only want to use the third instance of it.

Comment: One approach can be to get all the children of the common parent by 'getAllElements()' and then traverse to the target div through a loop where you check the class of the child.

Comment: Yes, but how do I differentiate from the classes if they are all named the same?  This is what I don't understand.  How would the loop find what I require?

Comment: If I understand correctly you need the third instance of the "blogbody", I would have an integer be incremented each time I get the a div with the class & break out of the loop when the counter hits 3.